# Javascript library for building desktop-like web application: ExtJS, jQuery, YahooUI, Mocha, SproutCore, Cappuccino, others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, yui, mootools

I am evaluating several Javascript UI toolkits for building web applications that have a desktop-like feel, mainly because of dialogs and window management.

I looked at several options - here are my evaluations so far:

- [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/) - Great widget library, great docs! Not so great license.
- [jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/) - Lack of ready-made window and dialog containers. I love jQuery though.
- [Yahoo! UI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) - Same problem as above. Really mature (but, unfortunately, [is no longer being actively maintained](https://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/96098168666/important-announcement-regarding-yui)) and well documented.
- [Mocha](http://mochaui.com/demo/) (Mootools-based) - Not as mature as the others. Lacks good documentation.
- [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) - Same as above. Also doesn't have window and dialog widgets.
- [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) - Too weird and revolutionary.

What's your take on these? Are my evaluations correct?

Comment: JQuery was written as a framework. There are tonnes of great plug-ins that will do what you are looking for. My personal favorite is JQuery.

Comment: You should be considering SmartClient.  Far, far richer than anything you've listed and a true LGPL license.  Look at the features of the 8.0 release - http://blog.isomorphic.com/?p=145

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of a desktop look/feel the best of that bunch has to be ExtJS.  In terms of the UI it really is leaps ahead of the rest.  Of course there are licensing issues but they have their FLOSS exceptions and if you intend to make money from the project then a commercial license isn't exactly going to break the bank.

Other Very Rich Framework worth looking at (all have their good and bad points),

- [Bindows](http://www.bindows.net/)
- [Tibco General Interface](http://www.tibco.com/devnet/gi/)
- [vegUI](http://www.vegui.org/)
- [Echo](http://echo.nextapp.com/site/echo3)

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about GWT (Google Web Toolkit http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/ )?

Comment: I second this suggestion. Used this UI technology at my workplace. It has a good community which covers for a rather small widget library and lack of DnD for example. Nice debugging features also.

Answer (score 4):

I love jQuery, plus its been adopted by M$ for MVC. I wouldnt call the lack of ready made stuff a downer. Yeah it would be great if there was, but with things like that i always find you end up bodging them to fit your needs, just write you own, its so easy to!

Answer (score 2):

YUI is very great at UI, except that the syntax is a little verbose, but hey, there are enough documentation on yahoo! site to get thing done correctly!

Answer (score 2):

You could give a try to [jQuery Desktop](http://desktop.sonspring.com/) or [ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/desktop/desktop.html).

Answer (score 1):

*If you want it to look like and work like a desktop app*, I would choose either [Yahoo! UI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [Ext.JS](http://extjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using ExtJS for some projects lately. It's learning curve is a bit steep, since you'll have to grasp their concept of layouts, but other than that you'll be fine.

Just make sure that you read the licensing agreement before you start using it. Oh, and ExtJS works fine using jQuery, Prototype and others.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is probably the best choice. It's fast, it's lean and it's damn beautiful.
Their support is also excellent.