# Javascript / DHTML / JQuery MDI / Desktop / Windowed environment

Tags: jquery-plugins, user-interface, open-source, desktop

I would like to develop a UI that includes draggable windows, a task bar showing open windows etc.

The main requirement beside the above is to have it in a contained area, a div or an iframe

I've found two great candidates, but they both failed, is there anything answering the above?

- http://widget-env.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=demo Is nice, but simply not there yet
- http://desktop.sonspring.com/ seems amazing, but only seems to work in full screen

I'm sure there are millions of free solutions, but I'm willing to consider a commercial one as well

Comment: In what way does the jQuery Desktop you linked "only work in full screen?" Do you mean that it only works by taking up the entire browser window?

Comment: As far as I can see, yes, I tried to embed it in an IFrame and it redirected to the actual content, e.g. like an anty frameset protection or something. also putting it in a DIV and limiting the size renders a broken UI. But I'll be glad to hear I'm wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start, there's this question, which is sort of old, but basically asks the same question you're asking: [Javascript library for building desktop-like web application: ExtJS, jQuery, YahooUI, Mocha, SproutCore, Cappuccino, others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268625/javascript-library-for-building-desktop-like-web-application-extjs-jquery-yaho)

Some other jQuery-based choices (I haven't tried implementing any of these myself):

- [jQuery Desktop](http://jquery-desktop.org/)
- [jDesktop](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jDesktop) (seems kind of slow)
- http://desktop.udjamaflip.com/ (seems rough around the edges)

If you don't mind a non-jQuery option, I recommend taking a look at YUI. It's is a top-notch library with many features & widgets, solid documentation, and a ridiculously high level of customizability. [YUI 2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/) is the current stable version; [YUI 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) is still in beta. It'll take a bit of custom CSS to make a YUI-based page look as slick as http://desktop.sonspring.com/, but you can definitely use the [Layout Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/layout/) to build [non-full-screen layouts](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/layout/).

For an OS-like feel, check out some of the menu demos:

- [OS-style programs menu example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/programsmenu_source.html)
- [Application menubar example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/applicationmenubar_source.html)

YUI plays perfectly well with jQuery, too.

Comment: Thanks!, I'll check all the above and report

Answer (score 1):

I think ExtJS has emerged as a poweful desktop like UI javascript library.

Comment: I meant a desktop environment as in windows (maximize, minimize) and taskbar (all minimized / open windows)